# Не перерисовывается компонент React

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  let names = ["Коля", "Вася", "Петя", "Иван", "Дима"];
  let [count, setState] = useState(0)
  let arr = []

  function handleClick() {
    setState(count + 1)
    arr = Array(count).fill('punkt')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {names.map((item, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
        })}
        {arr.map((item, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Задача: Вывести список имён и по нажатии на кнопку, добавлять li в конец списка. Возможно у меня странный подход, я для каждого нажатия кнопки прибавляю к count единицу и создаю массив с count кол-вом елементов, но почему-то нету ни ошибки ни норм результата. Чо так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, если правильно вас понял, для перерисовки лучше использовать callback в useState

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  let initialState = ['Коля', 'Вася', 'Петя', 'Иван', 'Дима'];
  let [name, setName] = useState(initialState);

  function handleClick() {
    setName((v) => [...v, 'value']);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {name.map((item, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: function handleClick() {
    setName((v) => [...v, 'value']);
}
как здесь работает троеточие и что вообще эта строка делает?

Comment: @maks троеточие это деструктуризация, если в кратце, мы берём старое значение => развёртываем в новый массив => добавляем в конец нового массива новое значени => благодаря колбеку перерисовываем компоненту

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны изменять отслеживаемую переменную. У вас же попытка вывести, не имеющие отношения к состоянию списки

```js
function App() {
  let names = ["Коля", "Вася", "Петя", "Иван", "Дима"];
  let [namesList, setNames] = useState(names)

  function handleClick() {
    namesList.push('new name');
    setNames(namesList)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {namesList.map((item, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Написал по памяти, не проверял работоспособность

[Использование хука состояния](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: Ошибок нету, но и ваш код не работает. Я сделал по Вашему образцу(думал я натупил), потом закопипастил и всеравно ничего.